# Tikz triangle with symbols

Tags: formatting, tikz-arrows

How do I change the A,B,C labelt to make them into math symbols?  For example say I want to change A to read $\mathbb{A}$?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document} % preamble added by a rodent ;-)
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){Z}
%
\tkzDefPoint(-0.7,-0.1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0.4,-0.3){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0.1,0.4){C}
%
%
%
\tkzClipCircle(O,Z)
%
\tkzMarkAngles[fill= orange,size=0.45cm,opacity=.3](B,A,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.35](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
\tkzMarkAngles[fill= orange,size=0.4cm,opacity=.3](C,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](C,B,A){$\beta$}
\tkzMarkAngles[fill= orange,size=0.3cm,opacity=.3](A,C,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.2](A,C,B){$\gamma$}
%
\tkzDrawCircle[fill,orthogonal through=A and B,color=white](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[fill,orthogonal through=A and C,color=white](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[fill,orthogonal through=B and C,color=white](O,Z)
%
\tkzDrawCircle(O,Z)
%
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=A and B,color=green](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=A and C,color=blue](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=B and C,color=red](O,Z)
%
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,fill=red,size=11](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} % line added by a rodent
```

Comment: Please edit your post to make your code compilable.

Comment: @cfr I made the code compilable but I do not know if it is OK to modify posts in such a way. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: @marmot I'm not sure. Maybe a question for Meta. I've sometimes done it. I mean: improving posts is encouraged. But then the question will be whether you can be sure you're not changing something essential, I guess, is it?

Comment: @cfr Yes, precisely. In the worst case you could introduce an error. Or you could just solve the problem, which might be fine with the OP, but might defeat the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `\tkzLabelPoint` (singular) instead of `\tkzLabelPoints` (plural).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} 
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){Z}
%
\tkzDefPoint(-0.7,-0.1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0.4,-0.3){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0.1,0.4){C}
%
\tkzClipCircle(O,Z)
%
\tkzMarkAngles[fill= orange,size=0.45cm,opacity=.3](B,A,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.35](B,A,C){$\alpha$}
%
\tkzMarkAngles[fill= orange,size=0.4cm,opacity=.3](C,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](C,B,A){$\beta$}
%
\tkzMarkAngles[fill= orange,size=0.3cm,opacity=.3](A,C,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.2](A,C,B){$\gamma$}
%
\tkzDrawCircle[fill,orthogonal through=A and B,color=white](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[fill,orthogonal through=A and C,color=white](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[fill,orthogonal through=B and C,color=white](O,Z)

%
\tkzDrawCircle(O,Z)

%
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=A and B,color=green](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=A and C,color=blue](O,Z)
\tkzDrawCircle[orthogonal through=B and C,color=red](O,Z)

%
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,fill=red,size=11](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoint[below](A){$\mathbb{A}$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above right](B){$\mathcal{B}$}
\tkzLabelPoint(C){$\boldsymbol{C}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]